# Database data in jquery dialog

Tags: php, jquery, foreach, jquery-dialog

Ok, i tried it with jquery ajax to achieve the same. But now the system always shows the first id. It doesn't matter at which edit_subscriber image i click. This is what i did:

Jquery code:

```
    jQuery(".edit_subscriber").click( function() {


    jQuery('.dialog-modal').dialog({
    modal: true,
    open: function ()
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'get',
            url: nieuwsbrief.editsubscriber,
            data: 'ajax=&subscriber_id=' + jQuery('.edit_subscriber').prop('id'),
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('.dialog-modal').html(data);
                }
        });
    },
    close: function ()
    {

    },         
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    title: 'Ajax Page'
});
    return false;
});
```

html code:

```
echo '<div class="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none;"></div>';
```

edit_subcriber.php:

```
<?php
 include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/www/wordpress/wp-config.php';
 include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/www/wordpress/wp-load.php';
 include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/www/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php';

 global $wpdb;

 echo $_GET['subscriber_id'];

 ?>
```

Comment: Ids must be *unique* per page, you cannot have several `#dialog-modal` elements in one page.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the script is, you are using same `id` for all dialog-models, and when you are clicking on the `edit_subscriber`, it is picking the dialog form the id, and as you are picking form id, it will always get the first element with the id.

Multiple element with same id is not valid.

So you can try this.

Just replace this code

```
echo '<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none;">
       Naam: <input type = "text" name = "subscriber_name" id = "'.$abonnee->subscriber_id.'" value = "'.$abonnee->subscriber_name.'"> <br />
</div>';
```

with this

```
 echo '<div class="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none;">
       Naam: <input type = "text" name = "subscriber_name" id = "'.$abonnee->subscriber_id.'" value = "'.$abonnee->subscriber_name.'"> <br />
</div>';
```

and change js function to :

```
jQuery(".edit_subscriber").click( function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next().dialog({
        modal: true,
        open: function (){},
        close: function (){},         
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        title: 'Ajax Page'
    });
});
```

As you are placing `div` after `tr` which is also not valid markup.

Comment: Thanks, i've changed it to class. But there is still a problem. Now i get 2 popups, in sequence, which contains the data in my database. So each popup contains a name from the database. It doesnt matter at which edit image i click, the system shows the same information over and over again.

Comment: did you changed your js function also or not?

Comment: Yes i did, but now only the last record pops up. And it gets deleted from the table.

Comment: Now its getting the information of the closest tr, but i dont want that. I want to get the information which is inside the div.

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').next('div.dialog-modal').dialog({` try with it.

Comment: Got it fixed with Ajax! had to put the jQuery(this).prop('id'); in a var. This in this case refers to jQuery(".edit_subscriber") from the click funtion!

Comment: Great! Glad to know, you have solved your problem yourself :)

Comment: Yograj Gupta, tnx for your time and sorry for my bad English!